# Search by Year via date (only 'date', not timestamp or other), PHP via passing from variable

Tags: php, mysql, database, date

so I am having an issue when creating a search function which prints results from a selected year. The user basically selects the year in which they would like to see all the tasks that took place in that year.

I have tried many functions and I am still learning myslqi so I do apologize for lack of this *currently on in mysql.

Here's what I have so far, I am getting no errors, I am not getting any errors, I am just not getting any results.

Here's the html where the user selects the year they want results from;

I have cut the code down to show the important parts;

First off here is the html year selection:

```
<table>
<div class="container-fluid">
<form>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="..." name="year" id="year" onclick="showYear(this.value)" class="form-control">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2015">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2015">2015</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2014">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2014">2014</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2013">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2013">2013</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2012">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2012">2012</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="..." name="year" id="year" onclick="showYear(this.value)" class="form-control">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2011">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2011">2011</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2010">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2010">2010</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2009">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2009">2009</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2008">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2008">2008</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="..." name="year" id="year" onclick="showYear(this.value)" class="form-control">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2007">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2007">2007</button>
    </div>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2006">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2006">2006</button>
    </div>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2005">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2005">2005</button>
    </div>
   <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2004">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2004">2004</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="..." name="year" id="year"onclick="showYear(this.value)" class="form-control">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2003">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2003">2003</button>
    </div>
   <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2002">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2002">2002</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2001">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2001">2001</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2000">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2000">2000</button>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
</table>

<div class="container-fluid" id="txtHint"><b></b></div>
```

There is a script at the top of this page to handle and pass this:

```
<script>
    function showYear(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getYear.php?year="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
    </script>
```

and here's the php:

```
<html>

<body>

<div class="container-fluid"> <!-- Table Headers -->
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Series:</th><th>Title:</th><th>Date:</th><th>Type:</th><th>House Location:</th><th>Housemates:</th>
            <br>
        </tr>
    </thead>      
</div>

<?php
$date = intval($_GET['year']);

include('dbconnect.php');

$sql ="SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE YEAR(date) = '$date' ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result)

echo "An error occurred: ".mysql_error();

else

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {

    $taskid = $row['taskid'];

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';

    echo '<button type="button" name="delete_row" id="delete_row" class="close">';
    echo '<a href="taskResult.php?id='. $taskid .'">';
    echo '<span title="View" aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">';
    echo '</span>';
    echo '<span class="sr-only">';
    echo 'View';
    echo '</span>';
    echo '</button>';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['houseLocation'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['housemates'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close();
?>
```

At the moment I am only getting the table headers printing on any selection?

Any help would be much appreciated. This is for very small project, I am a very new coder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you JS:

`xmlhttp` is undefined. try adding `var` before `xmlhttp` like:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

and

```
var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

OR

add `var xmlhttp` in the first line of your `else` block.

And your `onclick` method is added to wrong div in your html where as it should be added to the buttons:

Relace you HTML with this:

```
<table>
<div class="container-fluid">
<form>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="..." name="year" id="year"  class="form-control">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2015">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2015" onclick="showYear(this.value)">2015</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2014">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2014" onclick="showYear(this.value)">2014</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2013">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2013" onclick="showYear(this.value)">2013</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2012">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2012" onclick="showYear(this.value)">2012</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="..." name="year" id="year" class="form-control">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2011">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2011" onclick="showYear(this.value)">2011</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2010">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2010" onclick="showYear(this.value)">2010</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2009">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2009" onclick="showYear(this.value)">2009</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2008">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2008" onclick="showYear(this.value)">2008</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="..." name="year" id="year"  class="form-control">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2007">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2007" onclick="showYear(this.value)">2007</button>
    </div>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2006">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2006" onclick="showYear(this.value)">2006</button>
    </div>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2005">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2005" onclick="showYear(this.value)">2005</button>
    </div>
   <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2004">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2004" onclick="showYear(this.value)">2004</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="..." name="year" id="year" class="form-control">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2003">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2003" onclick="showYear(this.value)">2003</button>
    </div>
   <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2002">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2002" onclick="showYear(this.value)">2002</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2001" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2001" onclick="showYear(this.value)">2001</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" value="2000">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="2000" onclick="showYear(this.value)">2000</button>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
</table>

<div class="container-fluid" id="txtHint"><b></b></div>
```

Comment: Hi so i have done exactly that (it needed small tweaks, quotes & extra bracket) but still just getting the table headers with no results... baffling

Comment: string(9) "undefined"

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply, I have only just got to sit down to this! This worked perfectly! Thank you SO much!!!

Answer (score 0):

First thing that jumps out at me is that in your sql you are comparing a number to a string.

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE YEAR(date) = '$date' ;
```

By wrapping the $date inside quotes it becomes a string value. The numeric year value returned by YEAR(date) will never match against a string value.

i.e. 2015 != '2015'

Comment: Its a good catch. That could be it. But it depends on how strict a db engine your mysql server is set to use. So "The numeric year value returned by YEAR(date) will *never* match against a string value" is too strong. In all likelihood it won't, unless your db administrator set the server to be very loose.

Comment: @user2730024 thank you, such a small oversight. I'm idiot. I have removed the single quotes, still no results yet